I am getting this error, also installed all the dependencies, cleared npm cache, updated the version for dependencies. what could be the issue?
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js 68:16-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\gaxios\build\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js 70:38-60
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\gaxios\build\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js 75:17-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\gaxios\build\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/agent-base/dist/helpers.js 38:26-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\gaxios\node_modules\agent-base\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/agent-base/dist/helpers.js 39:27-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\gaxios\node_modules\agent-base\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/agent-base/dist/index.js 41:25-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\gaxios\node_modules\agent-base\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/agent-base/dist/index.js 42:26-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\gaxios\node_modules\agent-base\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/agent-base/dist/index.js 43:16-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\gaxios\node_modules\agent-base\dist'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
    - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/index.js 43:25-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\gaxios\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/https-proxy-agent/dist/index.js 44:25-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\gaxios\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\dist'
ERROR in ./node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/gcp-residency.js 22:13-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\gcp-metadata\build\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/gcp-residency.js 23:13-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\gcp-metadata\build\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/baseexternalclient.js 20:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/downscopedclient.js 20:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/externalAccountAuthorizedUserClient.js 23:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/filesubjecttokensupplier.js 22:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js 20:24-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js 21:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js 23:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
    - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js 24:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js 21:20-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js 22:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2common.js 20:20-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/pluggable-auth-handler.js 22:21-45
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/pluggable-auth-handler.js 23:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/stscredentials.js 21:20-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/crypto/node/crypto.js 20:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\crypto\node'
Did you mean './crypto'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/fallbackServiceStub.js 28:17-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-gax\build\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/paginationCalls/pageDescriptor.js 22:17-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\paginationCalls'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/routingHeader.js 22:20-42
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-gax\build\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/streamArrayParser.js 23:17-34
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-gax\build\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/streamingRetryRequest.js 19:4-21
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\google-gax\build\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js 25:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\gtoken\build\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js 28:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\gtoken\build\src'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/jwa/index.js 3:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\jwa'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/data-stream.js 3:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js 5:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js 5:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\jws\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
ERROR in ./node_modules/retry-request/index.js 5:4-21
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'E:\React Project\newsapp\node_modules\retry-request'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

This is a reactjs news app, trying to fetch audio from text through @google-cloud/text-to-speech, TextToSpeechClient.
